# Moving a div up and then down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have my code that supposes to animate div in a way that it moves up and then down. But it doesn't work and I don't know why.

```js
document.getElementById('div').style = 'width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: blue; left: 10px; bottom: 10px; position: absolute; animation-name: up; animation-duration: 2s;';
setTimeout(function() {
document.getElementById('div').style = 'width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: blue; left: 10px; bottom: 10px; position: absolute; animation-name: down; animation-duration: 2s;'
}, 2 * 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
document.getElementById('div').style = 'width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: blue; left: 10px; bottom: 10px; position: absolute;'
}, 2 * 1000);
```

```css
@keyframes up {
from (bottom: 10);
to (bottom: 50);
}
@keyframes down {
from (bottom: 50);
to (bottom: 10);
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: (1) Why use JS and not a simple CSS animation? (2) Please attach a working code snippet that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Can you show a little more CSS and your HTML?

Comment: @SafwanSamsudeen that's the only CSS I have in the document. And the HTML is this: `<div id="div"></div>`

Comment: @DominicentekGaming, the property `bottom`, `top`, `left`, and `right` can only be used on elements which have a property other than `static` (the default). Also, you are never using your animation in your code. @johannchopin's answer is correct, use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [translateY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY) property you can move an html element up or down. Just use it in a css animation and you are fine:

```css
@keyframes upToDown {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

Here you have the full example:

```css
div {
  background: red;
  margin-top: 50px;
  animation: upToDown 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes upToDown {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  a div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

css is enough!

```css
@keyframes upAndDown {
  0% {
    bottom: 5px;
  }

  100% {
    bottom: 10px;
  }
}

.wrapper {
        position: relative;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
      .content {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 5px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: red;
        animation: upAndDown 1s ease-in-out 2s infinite;
      }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
```